# JsonTypeError :Argument passed must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code.i can't create Jwt token

```
const getToken = async () => {
  const email = user?.user?.email
  if (email) {
    const { data } = await axios.post('https://powerful-dawn-49608.herokuapp.com/signin', { email })
  })
    setToken(data.getToken);
    localStorage.setItem('token', data.getToken);
  }
}
getToken()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.